# Why do I have two hands when I use the MATK component to modify the hand visualizer and play it in VR glasses?

Tags: virtual-reality, mrtk

I used the MRTK component to develop programs in Unity. I wanted the visualization of the hand to not always be the same as the actual hand position. I had modified RiggedHandVisualizer.cs in the MRTK component like this：

```
if (autoUpdate)
{
    jointTransform.position = handJointPose.Position;
}
else
{
    Vector3 temp = ConvertCoordinateScale(0.2F, oldPlace, handJointPose.Position);
    jointTransform.position = temp;
}
```

When I played it in Unity, I can complete the functions I want. But when I built the project into VR glasses Quest Pro, I had two hands when playing. One was in the desired position and the other in the same position as the real hand at all times. How can I turn off the hand that is in the same position as the real hand?
[play in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp2kk.png)
[play in VR glasses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjssL.png)

[before change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgmFE.png)
[after change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcWYa.png)
I tried to change the hand mesh visualization modes in the MRTK settings to editor, but after making the changes, I didn't have any hands left.